# como hago que el contador de clicks no se borre

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Tengo un contador de clicks en un boton, pero quiero que sea fijo la cantidad de clicks que se ha dado, que no se borren cuando un nuevo visitante entre, si no, que le siga mostrando la cantidad que se ha hecho, sin usar mysql ni php**

codigo:

```
<button id="view">click</button> 
window.onload =  function(){
var contador = 0;
document.getElementById("view").onclick = function(){
contador++;
alert(contador);
}
}
```

Comment: Vas a necesitar algo en el backend, no importa que sea PHP, asp, o algo. De lo contrario, solo con HTML, JavaScript o CSS va a ser imposible porque el contador se resetearía para cada usuario.

Comment: Vas a necesitar grabar esos datos sea en un archivo temporal en el servidor o en una base de datos..

Comment: Si no tienes un backend, siempre puedes usar un servicio como [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es-419) para mandar los datos a la nube a la hora de persistirlos, y luego recuperarlos cuando entre un nuevo visitante con el evento `window.onload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no tienes problemas de compatibilidad, una solución simple es usar la API de WebStorage y [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Algo así:

```
window.onload =  function(){
   // Revisar si ya hay algun dato guardado en la memoria. Si no, iniciamos con cero
   var contador = localStorage.getItem('contado') || 0; 
   document.getElementById("view").onclick = function(){
      contador++;
      // Guardamos el valor de contado en la memoria
      localStorage.contador = contador;
      alert(contador);
   }
}
```

Comment: Tu código me ha enseñado `localStorage`, pero creo que no ha solucionado el problema que plantea la pregunta. En particular no cumple: **que no se borren cuando un nuevo visitante entre**. Tu código sólo funciona con usuarios en el mismo navegador.

Comment: Ah, entiendo... En ese caso no hay otra manera más que uses una base de datos en un servidor. Te recomiendo usar firebase para esto, es facil de usar, rápido para implementar y no necesitas tener tu propio servidor.

Comment: El localStorage es único para cada usuario

Comment: @amenadiel tenés razón.